# Issue with importing Swift Framework to Xcode app project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I have a .xcworkspace with two xcode projects. One of them hosts a Swift Framework (ExpLib) and another one hosts iOS App (ExpApp). I have added the ExpLib framework as a dependency to the iOS App. But while compiling the app, I'm getting `No such module 'ExpLib'` Error. This error is thrown on the swift file on which I import the library.

The error occurs on the Compilation step. i.e.

```
ld: framework not found ExpLib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Below is the project setup I have

[image: Project setup]

Below are the App target's framework dependencies.

[image: App Framework dependencies]

**Note:**

I'm getting this error on an app we work on. However, when I tried to recreate this setup on an example project. I'm getting no such issues. Could someone see through what I'm missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the issue might be related to the build settings or configuration of your Xcode project. Here are a few steps you can check to resolve the "No such module 'ExpLib'" error:

**Build Configuration:**

Ensure that the ExpLib target is building for the correct architecture and SDK. Go to the build settings of the ExpLib target and verify that the "Valid Architectures" and "Build Active Architecture Only" settings are set correctly.

**Framework Search Paths:**

Check if the path to the ExpLib framework is correctly added to the "Framework Search Paths" in the build settings of your ExpApp target. It should point to the location where the ExpLib.framework is built.

**Library not Building:**

Make sure that the ExpLib target is successfully building and generating the ExpLib.framework. Check the build log to confirm that there are no errors during the build process.

**Module Map:**

Ensure that the ExpLib framework contains a proper module map file (module.modulemap) and that it is correctly configured. The module map file should declare the module and specify the framework header.

**Dependency Order:**

In your ExpApp target, check the "Target Dependencies" and "Link Binary With Libraries" build phases. Ensure that ExpLib is listed as a dependency and is linked correctly.

**Clean and Build:**

Sometimes, issues can be resolved by cleaning the build folder. In Xcode, go to "Product" in the menu and select "Clean Build Folder." Then try building the project again.

**CocoaPods or Carthage:**

If you are using CocoaPods or Carthage to manage dependencies, make sure that your dependencies are correctly configured and up to date. Try reinstalling them if needed.

**Xcode Workspace:**

Ensure that your ExpApp target is a member of the ExpLib workspace. Open the .xcworkspace file and check the project and target settings.

**Recreate Scheme:**

Try recreating the Xcode schemes for both ExpApp and ExpLib. Go to "Product" -> "Scheme" -> "Manage Schemes," and delete the existing schemes. Then, recreate them.

**Xcode Version:**

Ensure that you are using a compatible version of Xcode. Sometimes, issues can arise if there are compatibility issues between Xcode versions.

Comment: Found that the ExpLib.framework is created in a different directory so the main app could not find it. Had to update Framework Search Paths to make it work.